# Error reading/writing to properties of generic type using RTTI

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti

I am using a generic class to allow me to access a named property of a generic type and read/write its value. I am getting an EAccessViolation error when trying to access the result from a call to GetValue from a RTTIProperty record and also when setting a value using SetValue. When running a trace it seems both errors are being thrown when access the TValue. I have included a sample console app below that highlights the issue.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.RTTI;

Type
  TTestClass = class
  private
    FItem: string;
  public
    Property Item: string read FItem write FItem;
  end;

  TAccessData<T> = class
    Function GetTValue(AItem : T; AField : string) : TValue;
    Procedure SetTValue(AItem : T; Afield : string; AValue : TValue);
  end;

{ TAccessData<T> }

function TAccessData<T>.GetTValue(AItem: T; AField: string): TValue;
var
  LContext : TRTTIContext;
  LType : TRttiType;
  LProperty : TRttiProperty;

begin
  result := nil;
  LType := LContext.GetType(Typeinfo(T));
  LProperty := LType.GetProperty(Afield);
  if LProperty <> nil then
    Result := LProperty.GetValue(@AItem);
end;

var
  LTestObj : TTestClass;
  LAccessOBj : TAccessData<TTestClass>;
  AValue : TValue;

procedure TAccessData<T>.SetTValue(AItem: T; Afield: string; AValue: TValue);
var
  LContext : TRTTIContext;
  LType : TRttiType;
  LProperty : TRttiProperty;

begin
  LType := LContext.GetType(Typeinfo(T));
  LProperty := LType.GetProperty(Afield);
  if LProperty <> nil then
    LProperty.SetValue(@AItem, AValue);
end;

begin
  try
    LTestObj := TTestClass.Create;
    LTestObj.Item := 'Hello';
    Writeln(LTestObj.Item);
    LAccessOBj := TAccessData<TTestClass>.Create;
    AValue := LAccessObj.GetTValue(LTestObj, 'Item');
    Writeln(AValue.TypeInfo^.Name);
    if AValue.TypeInfo.Kind <> tkString then
      Writeln('Not string');
    Writeln(AValue.ToString); // <--- This results in a EAccessViolation
    LAccessOBj.SetTValue(LTestObj,'Item','World'); // <--- This results in a EAccessViolation
    Writeln(LTestObj.Item);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

I suspect I am missing something in the way I am accessing the properties of the generic types but have hit a wall as to why I am getting this behaviour. I have not made a constraint on the generic parameter as I need this to work with record types as well.

Using Tokyo update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `GetTValue` and `SetTValue` is defect as it passes `@AItem` to `TRttiProperty.SetValue` and `GetValue`. It needs to be `PPointer(@AItem)^` or constrain `T` to `class` so you can directly hardcast with `Pointer(AItem)`.

Due to the wrong passed `AInstance` the `TValue` contains some garbage memory which you can see if you introduce a string variable and assign the result of the `ToString` call to it before trying to pass it to `Writeln`. And the code in `Writeln` is then producing the AV.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, thought it might be something simple I had done wrong